# Unit Testing in Nim: Is it possible to get the name of a source file at compile time?

Tags: unit-testing, templates, nim-lang

I'm planning a project with multiple modules, and I was looking for a nice solution to run all existing unit tests in the project at once. I came up with the following idea: I can run `nim --define:testing main.nim` and use the following template as a wrapper for all my unit tests.

```
# located in some general utils module:
template runUnitTests*(code: stmt): stmt =
  when defined(testing):
    echo "Running units test in ..."
    code
```

This seems to be working well so far.

As a minor tweak, I was wondering if I can actually print out the file name which is calling the `runUnitTests` template. Is there any reflection mechanism to get the source file name at compile time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instantiationInfo seems to be what you want: http://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#instantiationInfo,

```
template filename: string = instantiationInfo().filename

echo filename()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! One minor note: I have to call `instantiationInfo().filename` directly in the `runUnitTests` template. If I create this `filename` template in my `utils.nim` module and call this second template from the `runUnitTests` template, the output is always `utils.nim` (looks like nesting templates affects stack line information).

Answer (score 5):

The template [currentSourcePath](http://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#currentSourcePath.t) from the system module returns the path of the current source by using a special compiler built-in, called `instantiationInfo`.

In your case, you need to print the locations of callers of your template, which means you'll have to use [instantiationInfo](http://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#instantiationInfo) directly with its default stack index argument of -1 (meaning one position up in the stack, or the caller):

```
# located in some general utils module:
template runUnitTests*(code: stmt): stmt =
  when defined(testing):
    echo "Running units test in ", instantiationInfo(-1).filename
    code
```

It's worth mentioning that the Nim compiler itself uses a similar technique with  [this module](https://github.com/Araq/Nim/blob/devel/compiler/testability.nim), which get automatically imported in all other modules by applying a [switch in nim.cfg](https://github.com/Araq/Nim/blob/0032912d101eb81134b82cb7cb7b0fe56fe97622/compiler/nim.nim.cfg#L10):